# Finding the most common occurrence in a Pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Let us say that I have a data frame where I want to associate users with countries:

```
>>> dfUsers[['userId', 'country', 'lat']].dropna().groupby(['userId', 'country']).agg(len).reset_index()

                 userId      country  lat
0   1479705782818706665        India    1
1   1480576924651623757        India   12
2   1480576924651623757           РФ    2
3   1480928137574356334     Malaysia   17
4   1480988896538924406        India    1
5   1481723517601846740     Malaysia    2
6   1481810347655435765    Singapore    3
7   1481818704328005112    Singapore    6
8   1482457537889441352    Singapore   18
9   1482488858703566411    Singapore    1
10  1482730123382756957        India    1
11  1483106342385227382    Singapore    2
12  1483316566673069712     Malaysia    4
13  1484507758001657608    Singapore    6
14  1484654275131873053    Singapore    1
15  1484666213119301417    Singapore    1
16  1484734631705057076     Malaysia    4
```

What I want to do, is to associate the *a user* with *a country*. In this case, it is easy to see that the user `1480576924651623757` has two different countries associated with him/her. However, I want to associate this user with `India` because the user has been in India more often than he/she has been in whatever that other country is ...

Is there a neat way of doing this? I can always loop over 'userId' and find the values corresponding to one that is larger. However, I am wondering if there is a way of doing this without the loop ...

Comment: `lat` column is for count `user` + `country` ?

Comment: Thats just a dummy column for the groupby ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for find max index per group by column `lat` and then select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('userId')['lat'].idxmax()]
print (df)
                 userId    country  lat
0   1479705782818706665      India    1
1   1480576924651623757      India   12 < 12 is max, so India
3   1480928137574356334   Malaysia   17
4   1480988896538924406      India    1
5   1481723517601846740   Malaysia    2
6   1481810347655435765  Singapore    3
7   1481818704328005112  Singapore    6
8   1482457537889441352  Singapore   18
9   1482488858703566411  Singapore    1
10  1482730123382756957      India    1
11  1483106342385227382  Singapore    2
12  1483316566673069712   Malaysia    4
13  1484507758001657608  Singapore    6
14  1484654275131873053  Singapore    1
15  1484666213119301417  Singapore    1
16  1484734631705057076   Malaysia    4
```

---

```
df = dfUsers[['userId', 'country', 'lat']].dropna()
                                          .groupby(['userId', 'country'])
                                          .size()
                                          .reset_index(name='Count')

df = df.loc[df.groupby('userId')['Count'].idxmax()]
```